# Displaying 2 images side by side with space (Css)

Tags: css, asp.net, html

I am displaying 2 images side by side in my webpage. I am trying to keep a space in between the 2 images but i am unable to do it. I have used css to display the images side by side.

Here is my Html Code :

```
 <div id="divCenter">

       <img src="Company Logo.jpg" alt="Company Logo" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="divIDOne"/>

          <%-- Code for the motion image --%>



      <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="animation.swf" width="719" height="174" id="divIDTwo">
      <param name="movie" value="animation.swf" />
      </object>

       </div>
```

Here is my css code :

```
 #divCenter {
    text-align: center;
 }

 #divIDOne {
     margin-right: 200px;
  }

 #divIDTwo {
     margin-left: 300px;
 }
```

Here is what it displays :

[image]

Ask you can see there is no space between the 2 images. How do i solve this problem?

Thank you for your time

Comment: they are not two images one is flash object. wrap both of them in div and then do you css class on those divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `text-align:center;` use `margin:0px auto;` and specify width and height property.
Try this.
HTML

```
<div id="divCenter">
       <img src="#" alt="Company Logo" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="divIDOne"/>
<!-- <%-- Code for the motion image --%> -->
      <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="animation.swf" width="780" height="174" id="divIDTwo">
      <param name="movie" value="animation.swf" />
      </object>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#divCenter {
  margin:0px auto;
  width:960px; 
  height:auto;
  padding:10px;
}

 #divIDOne {
     margin-right: 0px;
 }

 #divIDTwo {
   margin-left: 20px;
 }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5s6ck14q/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `padding` or `margin` to get space between two Images.

```
#divCenter {
    text-align: center;
}
#divCenter image {
    padding:2px;
    margin:2px;
}
```

But better approach is to keep the images in a container like `li` or `div` or `td`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the *display* property to the *inline* value i.e. `display=inline` and if required you can give some margin for the images this will add space between them. To be more precise you can set the `margin-left` property of the right image to desired value or the `margin-right` property of the left image to the desired value to add space between them .

Answer (score 0):

Use margin or padding for image

CSS:

```
#divCenter
{
     /*display:inline-block;*/ /*if need*/
     width:98%; /*your value*/
}
#divCenter img
{
     margin-right: 10px;     
}
```